# Lua Tester with a graphical output?

Tags: testing, graph, lua, drawing

I'm searching for a application or a service where I can test Lua code with graphical output.
Something like http://ideone.com or http://codepad.org, but not only text based output.

A lot of games use lua to script, in most of them are functions like draw_circle() and draw_line(). I need a tool that can output code with such functions on a 2D graph.
Something that can give me the result of code like this:

```
--should draw two circles and connect their centers with a line
--draw_circle(x, y, radius, color)
draw_circle(300, 300, 100, 0xff0000)
draw_circle(600, 300, 100, 0x00ff00)
--draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, width, color)
draw_line(300, 300, 600, 300, 1, 0x0000ff)
```

Is there something like that?
(Something in C or other languages would be nice too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've spent some time trying to getting the example working on Windows but all the solutions were too complex or/and required too much to install.

Instead, have found a very nice and powerful library called [CD (Canvas Draw)](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/cd/) with already [precompiled binaries for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/canvasdraw/files/5.6.1/Windows%20Libraries/)

(I used the `dynamic`/`Win32_dll8` version)

The library is so powerful that can output to a lot of system and with a lot of formats (svg, pdf etc.), but I'd like to output to a common window application, so another library is needed, [IUP](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/), again with [precompiled binaries for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iup/files/3.8/Windows%20Libraries/)

(again `dynamic`/`Win32_dll8`)

I had to extract both the libraries and [Lua5.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.1.4/Executables/lua5_1_4_Win32_bin.zip/download) to the same directory (but I guess there's some way on Lua to add search path for `.dll`)

Also an helper script is needed in the same directory [iupcdaux.lua](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/cd/examples/iupcdaux.lua)

**edit**

And there's the script to get the same output for your example:

app.lua:

```
require "iupcdaux"

dialog = iupcdaux.new_dialog(640, 480)
canvas = dialog[1]

function hex2rgb(hex)
    hex = string.format("%06x", hex)
    return cd.EncodeColor(tonumber("0x"..hex:sub(1,2)),
           tonumber("0x"..hex:sub(3,4)),
           tonumber("0x"..hex:sub(5,6)))
end

function draw_circle(x, y, r, rgb)
  canvas:LineWidth(1)
  canvas:Foreground(hex2rgb(rgb)) 
  canvas:Arc(x, y, r*2, r*2, 0, 360)
end

function draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, w, rgb)
  canvas:LineWidth(w)
  canvas:Foreground(hex2rgb(rgb))
  canvas:Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) 
end

function canvas:Draw(canvas)
  canvas:LineStyle(cd.CONTINUOUS) 
  dofile("script.lua")
end

dialog:show()
iup.MainLoop()
```

script.lua:

```
draw_circle(300, 300, 100, 0xff0000)
draw_circle(600, 300, 100, 0xff00)
draw_line(300, 300, 600, 300, 1, 0xff)
```

Here, this `app.lua` script look for a script `script.lua` with the same syntax of your example.

The minimal setup:

```
├── cd.dll
├── cdlua51.dll
├── app.lua
├── freetype6.dll
├── iupcdaux.lua
├── iupcd.dll
├── iup.dll
├── iuplua51.dll
├── iupluacd51.dll
├── lua5.1.dll
├── lua5.1.exe
├── Microsoft.VC80.CRT
│   ├── Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest
│   ├── msvcm80.dll
│   ├── msvcp80.dll
│   └── msvcr80.dll
├── script.lua
└── zlib1.dll
```

Comment: Thx for your work, but I'm searching something that is easier and faster than trying it in the actual game. But to set that all up and change the code that much would be more work than just starting the game itself ^^'

Comment: I'm not a Lua expert but I think you can wrap the function easily to obtain your wanted syntax, just make canvas a global, the setup are 3 unzip and 1 download for the helper script, much easier than it seem.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it later ^^

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's something already but embedding Lua in a C application and extending it with custom functions is really simple (if you know C), for the graphic I would suggest [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) and [SDL_gfx](http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/content/view/19/14/).

**edit**

Sorry it is for Linux don't know what are you using, also SDL_gfx doesn't support width for lines...

`apt-get install libsdl-gfx1.2-dev liblua5.1-0-dev`

Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2
CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config SDL_gfx --cflags)
LIBS += $(shell pkg-config SDL_gfx --libs)
CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config lua5.1 --cflags)
LIBS += $(shell pkg-config lua5.1 --libs)

all: test

test.o: test.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

test: test.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f test *.o
```

test.c:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_gfxPrimitives.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

#define lua_toUINT(L,i)       ((unsigned int)lua_tointeger(L,(i)))

static SDL_Surface *out;

/* draw_circle(x, y, radius, color) */
static int draw_circle(lua_State *L) {
    unsigned int x, y, r, color;
    x = lua_toUINT(L, 1);
    y = lua_toUINT(L, 2);
    r = lua_toUINT(L, 3);
    color = (lua_toUINT(L, 4) << 8) | 0xff;
    circleColor(out, x, y, r, color);
    return 0;
}

/* draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, width, color) */
static int draw_line(lua_State *L) {
    unsigned int x1, y1, x2, y2, color;
    x1 = lua_toUINT(L, 1);
    y1 = lua_toUINT(L, 2);
    x2 = lua_toUINT(L, 3);
    y2 = lua_toUINT(L, 4);
    /* width ignored SDL_gfx have not such thing */
    color = (lua_toUINT(L, 6) << 8) | 0xff;
    lineColor(out, x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Event event;
    int over = 0;
    lua_State *L;

    L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_register(L, "draw_circle", draw_circle);
    lua_register(L, "draw_line", draw_line);
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    out = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, 0);
    (void)luaL_dofile(L,"script.lua");
    SDL_UpdateRect(out, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    while (!over) {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                over = 1;
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

And here it is...

[image: result window]

Comment: It may be simple, but I'm not good with C ^^' I could change my code to C to test it, but I don't think that I could make a C application and embed it..

Comment: I'm writing a simple example for our fun, just wait :)

Comment: I use windows, but I'll setup a vm and test it.

Comment: Phew, I don't really know how to set this up xD

Comment: Maybe `cygwin` is an easy way but I'm not sure all the libraries are available, I'll give a try later and then let you know.